# Position a DIV on each side of 1 main DIV

Tags: css, html, position

How do I position 4 DIVs on the sides of another DIV?

1 on the north, 1 south, 1 west, 1 east.

```
<div id="frame">
  <div id="north"></div>
  <div id="east"></div>
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div id="south"></div>
  <div id="west"></div>
</div>
```

Note: frame is centered with `margin: auto;`. The `width` and `height` of `map` can change. Each Div around it should be neatless to the corr. border.

See this picture:

```
     |-------|
     |  n    |
|----|-------|----|
|  w |  map  |  e |
|----|-------|----|
     |  s    |
     |-------|
```

How can I do this best?

---

**EDIT:**

Thanks for the answers so far. I wanted the Navi Divs to be not absolute positioned but more like "linked" to the map Div. Sorry for lacking info.

I am now using jQuery's `mouseleave` function to determine the direction of the mouse movement when leaving the map. So this is done.

Comment: Are the widths of north, map and south independent of one another?

Comment: No the width of map, north and south are the same. These Divs are for catching the mouse movement to navigate.

Comment: Knocked up a jsfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/seSfK/1/

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by 'linked' to the map div? What do you consider 'linked'?

Comment: Should be neatless border to border. No logical linking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem: I am now using jQuery's mouseleave function to determine the direction of the mouse movement when leaving the map. So this is done.

Answer (score 4):

I have created a fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Astraldiva/Kt7PP/) demoing your example. It uses relative -> absolute positioning. It presumes you know exact width / height of the elements.

The Markup:

```
<div id="frame">
  <div id="north">north</div>
  <div id="east">east</div>
  <div id="map">map</div>
  <div id="south">south</div>
  <div id="west">west</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#frame {width: 450px; height: 450px; position: relative; margin: auto;}

#frame div {position: absolute; width: 150px; height: 150px;}

#map {top: 150px; left: 150px; background-color: orange;}

#east {right: 0px; top: 150px; background-color: yellow;}

#west {left: 0px; top: 150px; background-color: blue;}

#north {left: 150px; top: 0; background-color: green;}

#south {left: 150px; bottom: 0; background-color: gray;}
```

I used some bg colors so it is more visibly clear.

Hope it helps.